# Anychart DataArea Background Stroke Partly Not Visible

Tags: charts, background, fill, stroke, anychart

I want to draw a border around the data area of my chart. Therefor I use `chart.dataArea().background().stroke()` but the stroke is partially hidden behind the background fill color of the data area.

See this playground example:
https://playground.anychart.com/LfsMXtpR

Of course I could just make it thicker, but I want it to be the same thickness all around.
I think the stroke shouldn't be hidden by the background fill.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that yAxis has greater zIndex then data-area. You can decrease the yAxis zIndex to solve it, check [the modified sample](https://playground.anychart.com/5NHZ82go).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The zIndex is a great tipp, but I forgot to include grids in my example. Here is the updated one: https://playground.anychart.com/wfGLT6yz

I can't figure out how to set the zIndex of all the elements to make the stroke visible again.

Comment: Can you take a look at the new example? I think with the combination of chart grids, axes and dataArea border it is not possible to see the whole stroke around the data area. There's always something overlapping.

Comment: Grids can't be placed behind the data area background, because the background is not transparent. On the other hand, grids cover the background stroke. To avoid it you should prohibit drawing the first and the last line of grids. Here is the modified sample - https://playground.anychart.com/N14HRt6f